# How to merge hash of hashes and set default value if value don't exists

Tags: ruby, hash

I need to merge values of hash **a** into **out** with sort keys in  **a**.

```rb
a = {"X"=>{12=>1, 11=>4}, "Y"=>{11=>5}, "Z"=>{12=>5}}

out = [
  {"X": [4, 1]},
  {"Y": [5, 0]},
  {"Z": [0, 5]},
]
```

Comment: Are your keys always `11` and `12`?

Comment: No.. It can be different, but structure is the same: "NAME" => "num_key" => num_val

Comment: Why are there zeroes for Y and Z in the output? Why are they on different positions?

Comment: I need it for represent chart data

Comment: Well, I need to have a hash with merged values. So I want to sort the keys of "X", "Y", "Z", then in time of merging if internal hash don't have value for ex. 11 then I need to put 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
a = {"X"=>{12=>1, 11=>4}, "Y"=>{11=>5}, "Z"=>{12=>5}}

sorted_keys = a.values.flat_map(&:keys).uniq.sort
#=> [11, 12]
a.map { |k, v| { k => v.values_at(*sorted_keys).map(&:to_i) } }
#=> [ { "X" => [4, 1] }, { "Y" => [5, 0] }, { "Z" => [0, 5] }]
```

Answer (score 1):

**Code**

```
def modify_values(g)
  sorted_keys = g.reduce([]) {|arr,(_,v)| arr | v.keys}.sort
  g.each_with_object({}) {|(k,v),h| h[k] = Hash.new(0).merge(v).values_at(*sorted_keys)}
end
```

**Example**

```
g = {"X"=>{12=>1, 11=>4}, "Y"=>{11=>5}, "Z"=>{12=>5}}
modify_values(g)
  #=> {"X"=>[4, 1], "Y"=>[5, 0], "Z"=>[0, 5]}
```

**Explanation**

The steps are as follows (for the hash `a` in the example). First obtain an array of the unique keys from `g`'s values (see [Enumerable#reduce](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce) and [Array#|](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-7C)), then sort that array.

```
b = a.reduce([]) {|arr,(_,v)| arr | v.keys}
  #=> [12, 11] 
sorted_keys = b.sort
  #=> [11, 12]
```

The first key-value pair of `a`, together with an empty hash, is passed to `each_with_object`'s block. The block variables are computed using *parallel assignment*:

```
(k,v),h = [["X", {12=>1, 11=>4}], {}] 
k #=> "X" 
v #=> {12=>1, 11=>4} 
h #=> {}
```

The block calculation is then performed. First an empty hash with a *default value* `0` is created:

```
f = Hash.new(0)
  #=> {}
```

The hash `v` is then merged into `f`. The result is hash with the same key-value pairs as `v` but with a default value of `0`. The significance of the default value is that if `f` does not have a key `k`, `f[k]` returns the default value. See [Hash::new](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Hash.html#method-c-new).

```
 g = f.merge(v)
   #=> {12=>1, 11=>4} 
 g.default
   #=> 0 (yup)
```

Then extract the values corresponding to `sorted_keys`:

```
 h[k] = g.values_at(*sorted_keys)
   #=> {12=>1, 11=>4}.values_at(11, 12) 
   #=> [4, 1]
```

When `a`'s next key-value pair is passed to the block, the calculations are as follows.

```
(k,v),h = [["Y", {11=>5}], {"X"=>[4, 1]}] # Note `h` has been updated 
k #=> "Y" 
v #=> {11=>5} 
h #=> {"X"=>[4, 1]}
f = Hash.new(0)
  #=> {} 
g = f.merge(v)
  #=> {11=>5} 
h[k] = g.values_at(*sorted_keys)
  #=> {11=>5}.values_at(11, 12) 
  #=> [5, 0] (Note h[12] equals h's default value)
```

and now

```
h #=> {"X"=>[4, 1], "Y"=>[5, 0]}
```

The calculation for the third key-value pair of `a` is similar.